# Magento swatches 1.9.1 non latin characters usage

Tags: swatches

the swatches in the website are working fine.

I have attributes in native language (Lithuanian) thus I am using non latin characters in file names of swatches.

Thus the situation is as follows the translated images of swatches which have only latin characters shows up perfectly, however non latin character swatches don't show.

Here a screen of filterable navigation http://prntscr.com/71br65

I have swatches named žydra.png and it doesn't show.

Any fix to this?

---

Magento Community Ed. 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh got the solution. In this case when only several characters max are non latin in the word I can use **hyphens** in **swatches images files names** thus Magento see's the **hyphen as any symbol**. And now all swatches are working like charm :)